# Change part of an anchor link attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm trying to change the middle part of the URL when the proper radio button is clicked.

In the three purchase links each one represents an amount. I'm going to be selecting an animal then clicking on 1 of 3 amounts I want to spend. How would I change part of all 3 of the URLs?

How could I go about doing that? These are the radio buttons (with JavaScript):

```
<input type="radio" name="orderID" 
    value="-DOL&linkID=naib&url=https%3A//example.com/List%3FlinkID%3Dnaib"
    onclick="document.getElementById('editBTN').href=this.value">
    Dolphin
</input>
<input type="radio" name="orderID" 
    value="-SHK&linkID=naib&url=https%3A//example.com/List%3FlinkID%3Dnaib"
    onclick="document.getElementById('editBTN').href=""+this.value">
    Shark
</input>
```

And the purchase links (250$, 100$ and 50$, respectively):

```
<a id="editBTN" href="http://example.com/Info?ticketCode=%XX%3A%Q250">Purchase</a>
<a id="editBTN" href="http://example.com/Info?ticketCode=%XX%3A%Q100">Purchase</a>
<a id="editBTN" href="http://example.com/Info?ticketCode=%XX%3A%Q50">Purchase</a>
```

The `DOL` part is the only part that needs to change.

Comment: What part would you like to change into what? Could you give a clear example?

Comment: The "DOL" part is the only part that needs to change.

Comment: start out by not having 3 tags with the same id. id's have to be unique to a page. more than one, and you won't get the effects on the second one to the last one found.

Comment: Hmm. Okay so I have 3 purchase links. Each one represents an amount. I'm going to be selecting an animal then clicking on 1 of 3 amounts I want to spend. 

How would I change part of all 3 of the urls?

Comment: Also, it's better to use `onselect` instead of `onclick`, for the Javascript.

Comment: jmendeth when I use onselect instead of onclick the script doesn't seem to change the URL as all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to rename the Id's on your buttons to be unique, make a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAnimal(obj) {
        var baseURL="http://ev8.evenue.net/cgi-bin/ncommerce3/SEGetEventInfo?ticketCode=%3ANAIB%3A%3AAQ";
        document.getElementById('editBTN1').href=baseURL+"250&"+obj.value;
        document.getElementById('editBTN2').href=baseURL+"100&"+obj.value;
        document.getElementById('editBTN3').href=baseURL+"50&"+obj.value;
    }
</script>
```

and then, on the radio buttons do:

```
onclick="setAnimal(this);"
```

Comment: Or maybe you don't need the ampersand in there. I'm not sure how you're wanting it. Either way, the += operator should get you there. Good luck!

Comment: Mmmm, every time the user clicks an option, the URL will get larger, instead of replacing the already-set value...

Comment: Good catch, jmendeth. I'll modify.

Comment: onclick="document.getElementById('editBTN').href+=this.value"

This works but only for the first <a href> and it doesn't work if I switch back and forth between the two.

Comment: Try the modified version. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't seem to add the then value from the radio button.

Comment: Mmmm, you should have gotten an error if copied directly; I left out the ending semicolons on some lines. My bad.

Comment: @JonathanM let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1706/discussion-between-kelbizzle-and-jonathan-m)

Comment: I looked it up. There is no onselect in the standard for radio buttons. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('editBTN').href='http://ev8.evenue.net/cgi-bin/ncommerce3/SEGetEventInfo?ticketCode=%3ANAIB%3A%3AAQ250'+this.value;"
```

Comment: This url won't be the same for each animal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no middle part, use regular expressions, to cut the string and use the one you want. Changing it is quite easy:

```
var edBTN = getElementById('editBTN');
edBTN.setAttribute('href', mynewurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery or another dom parsing library this should be possible.

```
if ( /* radio selected */ ) {

    // Go get your src attrib
    var src = jQuery( 'selectorforanchortag' ).attr('src');
    // Manipulate the src however you need using javascript string methods
    src = src.blergetyblerg();
    // Put your new src back where orig was
    jQuery( 'selectorforanchortag' ).attr('src');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('editBTN').href=this.value">
```